Installing Graph Connector on SharePoint Foundation 2013?
I have heard that it could be problem in installing the new Graph Connector Agent (was in preview 2021) on SharePoint foundation 2013. But when you read articles they just mentioned SharePoint 2013 and not specify Server or Foundation version. This is on-prem we are talking about.
We need to make a decision of how to extract content and documents from this old version. This agent could really help out.
Do anybody have any experience of this and is it possible to install this agent?
